# SSRS Reports. Making summary tables for each group of records

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am building an SSRS sub-report that displays a table of grouped records. At the end of the report there is another table that summarizes the records of the entire table above. What I need is for the summary table to appear after every grouping of records. The information inside the summary table is generated using SSRS expressions such as the one below.

```
    =FormatNumber(AVG(Fields!Value1.Value, "Information") - Parameters!Value2.Value, 2)
```

How can I make multiple summary tables for each group of records within the first table, instead of one summary report for all of the records from every group. Currently I am trying to make a sub-report. There is two tables for one grouping of records per sub-report, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a row into your table underneath the details row for your group.  This one row will then be repeated after all your data for each group.  You can then put your sub-report into this row and it will appear at the end of each group.

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply. Is there a way that I can have the sub report generated for the specific group and one group at a time right after the group? Basically I need to take an average of one column belonging to any specific group and then display it underneath the group.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay on accepting your answer, I have solved the problem since then. But I find that your answer will be helpful to anyone who encounters a similar problem. Cheers.